# Inconsistent behavior in Microsoft Word for downloaded Word documents

Tags: microsoft-word, internet-explorer

Using Internet Explorer, when I click a link on a web page that links to a Microsoft Word document, Microsoft Word opens the file differently depending on where I save the file.

Why does this happen?

- If I choose to "Open" the file, the file opens in Protected View and displays in Print Layout view.
- If I choose to "Save As" the file, and then save
  it to the hard drive, the file opens in Protected View and displays in Read Mode view.
- If I select "Save As", and then save it to a flash drive, the file does NOT open in Protected View and displays in Print Layout view.

I am using Microsoft Word 2016.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard behavior of documents opened in MS word, in an attempt to protect your computer from potentially unsafe files. Files will open in protected view if any of the following criteria are met:

1) File is opened from an internet location.

2) File was received as an outlook attachment and sender is not marked as a safe sender.

3) The file is opened from a potentially unsafe location, for example your temp folder... this is considered an unsafe location.

4) File validation failure, file did not pass validation.

5) File was intentionally opened in protected view by using the 'open in protected view' option.

... and probably more. These are just a few of the reasons from the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It is a file downloaded from the internet, so I totally expect it to open in Protected View. However, I'm confused as to why it *doesn't* open in Protected View when saved to my flash drive. And why it sometimes defaults to Print Layout view, and sometimes defaults to Read Mode view. Very strange!